# Putting current time into label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datetime

Ii am trying to get date and time using date but when i run application it takes first time executed application time and date in short time is not changed.

```
NSDate *StrDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *Dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [Dateformat setDateFormat:@"DD-MM-YYYY"];
        NSMutableString *DateStr = [Dateformat stringFromDate:StrDate];
        [UserCntrl.timeDisplay setText:DateStr];
        [Dateformat setDateFormat:@"HH:MM"];
        NSMutableString *timeStr=[Dateformat stringFromDate:StrDate];
```

Comment: Please take the time to format the code in your question appropriately (using the "{}" editor control).

Comment: Two things: (1) please reformat your code. (2) don't use capitalized variable names in Objective-C (change `StrDate` to `strDate` or, better yet, `currentDate`).

Comment: @sam, also, you should accept answers.  People will be more willing to spend the time to answer your questions if you accept the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a scheduled timer in your uiview did show (or did load) method:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f // 1 second
    target:self
    selector:@selector(updateTime:) 
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

Then, put this method in your View Controller:

```
- (void) updateTime:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *StrDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *Dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [Dateformat setDateFormat:@"DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS"];
        NSMutableString *DateStr = [Dateformat stringFromDate:StrDate];
        [UserCntrl.timeDisplay setText:DateStr]; // or whatever code updates your timer.  I didn't check this for bugs.
}
```

This will call the "updateTime:" method once a second, updating your controller.

Answer (score 0):

[NSDate date] makes a date object of the time you call it. You must call it again to update the date. In other words, you must do StrDate = [NSDate date]; whenever you want to get the current date in your method.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code:
Instead of 
`[Dateformat setDateFormat:@"HH:MM"];`
it should be 
`[Dateformat setTimeFormat:@"HH:MM"];`